# Unable to create application in SCCM 2012

Tags: sccm-2012-r2

I am very new to SCCM and unfortunately the systems admin does not really know anything about it either. I am trying to add a new application and I receive the following error:

> Error: The SMS Provider reported an error connecting to the ConfigMgr
>   site database server. Verify that the SQL Server is online and that
>   ConfigMgr site server computer account is an administrator on the
>   ConfigMgr site database server.

My login account should have full SCCM rights, are there some additional rights that I am missing? I apologize for the beginner question, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error with your permissions - read it again. Either the SQL Server hosting the SCCM database is offline/unhealthy, or the SCCM site server's **computer account** does not have the correct permissions to the SCCM database.

Comment: wouldn't this be the windows account used to log in to the sccm server? my user account should have full access and control of sccm.

Comment: No. The computer actually has it's own account separate from the user, and SCCM uses the computer account for most of these things. If the SQL Server database is installed on the same system as the site server (the default), this is rarely a problem. If SCCM connects to a Sql Server DB hosted elsewhere, you have to do extra work for the computer account to access the DB.